# Wildcard SSL Certificate for subdomains / sub.sub.domain.com

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I've got approximately 9 web servers running Ubuntu 12.04 with openssl.

all have the same primary domain of whatever.com  , Although some are sub.whatever.com and others are sub.sub.whatever.com

Is there a type of SSL Certificate which can be used on all domains / sub domains ?

So I could install it on sub.sub.sub.sub.whatever.com if I wanted to?

Answer (score 2):

Wildcard SSL only works on subdomain.domain.com and you can just add sub.sub.sub.domain.com as SANs to this certificate. Right now I'm using https://www.globalsign.com/ssl/multi-domain-ssl/ its quite expensive but its worth it.